# How to debug in developer tools when scripts compiled with jawr?

Tags: javascript, debugging, developer-tools, jawr

When running my project locally, or if it's running in a production like environment jawr compresses my javascript files so when I run developer tools and try and debug those files, I can only view the compressed file. How can I make it so I can view the original, uncompressed javascript files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information on debug and production modes related to jawr can be found [here](https://j-a-w-r.github.io/docs/modes.html)

From the link:

`While running in production mode, you may view your bundles in debug mode by using jawr.debug.overrideKey. This can be very helpfull when you need to debug issues in a production environment. Simply append overrideKey=(jawr.debug.overrideKey value) to the end of the url. Now your production bundles will be exploded; but only for that request. You may also view individual css and js files by adding the overrideKey to the end of the request.`

So in order to debug in production or locally you would add overrideKey=debug to the end of your url.

`url.com/something?overrideKey=debug`